# Pass value to update class, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following class defined in my CustomCell to create a circular indicator in a tableViewCell with a color fill.

```
class CircleView: UIView {

var gotColour = UIColor.clearColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
     let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
     gotColour.setFill()
     CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)
}
}
```

Depending on the result I need to update the color of the indicator (much like the iOS Mail app) through the gotColor variable. I try to do this in my TableViewController as follows:

```
cell.cellIndicator.gotColour = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

But this doesn't seem to work. For info: cellIndicator is a referencing outlet attached to a UIView in my cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call setNeedsDisplay on your CircleView when setting gotColour to make sure drawRect is fired.

```
var gotColour = UIColor.clearColor() {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```